# Template tag polyfill for IE 11 - not working with table tr and td

Tags: javascript, html, templates, polyfills, html5-template

I work with polyfill js that allows to process  tags for browsers that does not support it.

Source code of polyfill on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brianblakely/h3EmY/)

Source [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055275/html-templates-javascript-polyfills)

But I've noticed that in IE 11 this polyfill fails to work with templates that include `<tr>` and `<td>` tags

My sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kk1pj0hv/2/)

The problem is that when we try to get childNodes from template tag node

```
elPlate.childNodes
```

it returns everything but `<tr>` and `<td>` children as if there were no such tags inside `<template>`.

Am I missing something? Is there any workarounds for this issue?

P.S I was not able to add a comment to source issue due to lack of reputation. Sorry for that.

Comment: I've had the same problem, and there is also an issue on the WebComponents polyfill: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/632 You could work around using <div> and display: table(-cell) (but of course it's not semantic then). Interestingly, <li> without a container (<ul> or <ol>) works.

Answer (score 8):

This is happening because `<tr>` must be inside a `<table>` in order to be valid HTML. In your `<template>`, you have specified a loose `<tr>` that doesn't have a `<table>` parent. IE sees this as an error and removes it from the DOM. Hence, your template's `documentFragment` does not contain the `<tr>` and `<td>`.

The unfortunate fact is: IE is simply not ready for HTML5 template tags. It'd probably take a loooong while for Microsoft to implement it, and for the existing IE browser versions become truly obsolete. Only then can we reliably start using HTML5 template tags.

The workaround is: do not use `<template>`; explore template solutions using `<script type="template">` instead. I believe they should work well. Some popular ones:

- https://mustache.github.io/
- http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can work your way around it if you really want to work with `<tr>` in templates in IE11.

What you do is, instead of putting the `<tr>` directly in the templates, you put in an entire table like so

```
<template>
   <table>
      <tr>
         //foo bar
      </tr>
   </table>
</template>
```

This causes IE11 to no longer "correct" your HTML and return it as is. Once you cloned the HTML from the template, you can then extract the `<tr>` correctly out of the table and use it wherever it's needed.