# "invalid" table markup embedded in template tags are being "fixed" by IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

**edit**: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384954/template-tag-polyfill-for-ie-11-not-working-with-table-tr-and-td) is essentially the same problem, and has a (rather unfortunate) solution.

I have the following template tags in my markup:

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td width="110">&lt;%=date %&gt;</td>
        <td width="100%">
            <div class="bonus-withdrawal-list__spacer u-float-left"></div>
            <p class="u-float-left">
            &lt;%=description %&gt;
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="u-text-no-wrap">Kr &lt;%=amount %&gt;</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Usually one would get the content of that template with `document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0].innerHTML` or similar, but in IE11 all the `tr` tags and `td` tags are stripped out, leaving me with a very different DOM in IE than on more modern browsers. Since *all the other templates work fine* this seems to boil down to IE 11 encountering invalid HTML that it tries to make valid. `tr` and `td` tags with no `table` tag around it is invalid, so it tries to fix it. If only it knew that the `template` tag makes this different in HTML5 ...

Now, the problem remains: how can I fix this? Neither the `children` property nor `innerHTML` gives me the actual content. All I want is the untouched html tree as string content.

Comment: [IE11 does not support the template element.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template)

Comment: For IE11, wrap it in an actual table with display none. That way you have the spirit of the template tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384954/template-tag-polyfill-for-ie-11-not-working-with-table-tr-and-td

Comment: @Quentin I know IE11 does not "support" the template tag. That makes no difference here. The spec says (in brief) it should regard unknown tags as block elements.

Comment: @dmoo Thanks for the tip. That was exactly as I suspected. I was already implementing that solution as a temporary fix. Closing as duplicate of that.