# HTML Template Element: Clarification

Tags: javascript, html, templates, html5-template

I have recently discovered the HTML `template` element, and would appreciate some clarification.

As far as I can tell, the three distinguishing features are:

- `template` is not rendered on screen
- `template` does not make its way to the DOM
- there is an additional `content` property which acts as a virtual element between the `template` and its contents

Aside from these, a `<template>` might have been a `div`, hidden from the screen and the DOM. In this regard, the JavaScript used to take advantage of the `template` is the same as if trying to fake one using a `div`.

Is this correct? I ask because it would be relatively easy to fake one for nonsupporting browsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some major differences:

1. **Script** (`<script>`) in a `<template>` element is **not executed** immediately.
2. **Media content** (`<audio>`, `<video>`, `<img>`) inside the template **won't be loaded** immediately.

   Instead they will be executed or loaded **once they are inserted** in the rendered DOM tree.
3. `querySelector()` method calls and CSS **selectors won't explore** the content of a `<template>`, but you can still access the elements inside by using `querySelector()` on its `content` property.
4. With HTML5 template, you can access all its content in the form of a [Document Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), and insert it in the DOM tree using `appendChild()`, instead of modifying `innerHTML`.
5. `<template>` elements can be placed in the `<head>` element.
6. You access the template content as a string using `.innerHTML` or as a DocumentFragment using `.content`.

It's quite difficult then to fake all thses behaviors. There are [some polyfills](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16055275/4600982) that can partially do that. I'd recommend [Neovov's one](https://github.com/neovov/template-element-polyfill).

---

Look at this illustrative example:

```js
//explore the content of the template
var script = T1.content.querySelector( 'script' )
console.log( script.innerHTML )

function insert() {
  //insert the real templete
  Target1.appendChild( T1.content.cloneNode( true ) )
  //insert the fake template
  Target2.innerHTML += D1.innerHTML
}
```

```html
<template id=T1>
  Real Template -
  <script>console.log( 'executed at each insertion' )</script>
</template>

<div hidden id=D1>
  Fake Template -
  <script>console.log( 'executed only at parsing' )</script>
</div>

<button onclick="insert()">insert</button>

<div id=Target1><div>
<div id=Target2><div>
```

Comment: Just to add to your list: 6. You access the template content using `template.content` . I notice, however that you still have to clone the content — it’s not done automatically, which is what the word __template__ might suggest. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the template tag is exactly what it sounds like.
It is just a template for the JavaScript to create in the future.

It is slightly different from a hidden `<div>` though, but basically you are right and it can be faked with a hidden `div`

Imagine this scenario where you have a webpage with 2 inputs, one that enters your name and one that enters your age. By using a `template` tag to create a simple table, you can then use JavaScript to populate the table with your inputs, in the same page.

This article has a good read on it:
https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-template-tag/